# Select specific key from hash in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-hash

I have the following JSON which I convert to hash:

```
<%
  json = '{
    "speed": 50,
    "braking": 50,
    "time_on_task": 50
  }'
  json = JSON.parse(json)
%>
```

And currently I just loop through them and display them:

```
<ul>
  <% json.each do |t| %>
      <li><%= "<b>#{t.first.humanize}</b>: #{t.last}".html_safe %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

However I'd like to build a method that can pick an particular item by its key name. e.g. `show_score(json, 'speed')`

I tried:

```
def show_score(hash, key)
  hash.select { |k| k == key }
end
```

Which just returns: `{"speed"=>50}`

So I tried:

`hash.select { |k, h| "<b>#{k.humanize}</b>: #{h}".html_safe if k == key }`

But it returns the same...

How can I get to just return the string in the format I want if they key matches?

Comment: you don't need a method for that..they work as hash[:key]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def show_score(hash, key)
  "<b>#{key.humanize}</b>: #{hash[key]}"
end
```

And I'd change this

```
<%
  json = '{
    "speed": 50,
    "braking": 50,
    "time_on_task": 50
  }'
  json = JSON.parse(json)
%>
```

into

```
<%
  hash = {
    "speed" => 50,
    "braking" => 50,
    "time_on_task" => 50
  }
  json = hash.to_json
%>
```

Comment: Doing that just returns `50` when doing `json['speed']` How do I print the string I want by passing the key?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking too hard, or maybe I'm not understanding your question fully.

```
<ul>
  <% json.each do |k,v| %>
      <li><%= "<b>#{k.humanize}</b>: #{v}".html_safe %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

ps. using `Enumerable#detect` is so much faster than `Enumerable#select.first`